# passing only first element of the array of chars to a function c++

Tags: c, string, chars

Basically I have an array of words

```
 void print(char *str) {
 cout << str <<endl;
 }

 int main() {
 int i =0;
 char* name[] = {"Fred", "John", "Jimmy"};
 print(*name[0]);
 }
```

I would like to pass only first word to a function, but when I am doing in a way as I am doing right now it passes all the names.

Comment: What you have should not compile.

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra dereference there, the code should be like this:

```
print(name[0]);
```

Ideally, your `print` function should take `const char*`, because it does not modify the strings passed in.

Comment: It should be noted that the code is not quite correct though. It's not const-correct.

Comment: Also note that `name` points to string literals, but is not declared as such :)

Comment: While we're at it, why are we using a C array of C strings, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

`char* name[]` is an array of pointers to char, typically strings.

`void print(char *str)` requires a single pointer to a char as an argument.

By calling `print(*name[0])`, you are actually taking the first pointer from your name[] array, and dereferencing it to turn it into a single char. Since your function requires a pointer to char, you simply need to call it with `print(name[0])` and you'll get the first item in your array.